# gradient propagation through TensorArray

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm not sure I have understood how to use TensorArray's correctly in while_loops. I'm not getting the gradients I expect - infact I get a [None] gradient when I expect one.

Below is a small example of when the TensorArray does not compute gradients as I expected it to :

```
a = tf.TensorArray(  dtype=DTYPE, size=10, clear_after_read=False, )
a = a.write(0, tf.Variable(initial_value=1) )

b = tf.TensorArray(  dtype=DTYPE, size=10, clear_after_read=False,)
b = b.write( 0, a.read(0) * 3 )
b = b.write( 1, b.read(0) * 3 )

tf.gradients( b.read(0), a.read(0) )
>> [None]

tf.gradients( b.read(1), b.read(0) ) 
>> [None]
```

Have I misunderstood how this thing works ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you figured this out by now but posting an answer anyways. You are making new operations when you are trying to calculate gradients. Consider that grad(var+1, var) gives a gradient but grad(var+1, tf.identity(var)) gives None. Your code is not working for the same reason.

Compare to this code:

```py
DTYPE = tf.float32
var = tf.Variable(initial_value=1, dtype=DTYPE)
a = tf.TensorArray(dtype=DTYPE, size=10)
a = a.write(0, var)
a_0 = a.read(0)

b = tf.TensorArray(dtype=DTYPE, size=10)
b = b.write(0, a_0 * 3)
b_0 = b.read(0)
b = b.write(1, b_0 * 3)
b_1 = b.read(1)

print(tf.gradients(a_0, var))
print(tf.gradients(b_0, var))
print(tf.gradients(b_0, a_0))
print(tf.gradients(b_1, b_0))
```